# Return an item that differs from related items based on a property using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

So I have a list of objects, let's call them Elephants.

Each elephant object has a property called ClonedFrom. This is of type Elephant and is used to point back at the object that this new object was created in the image of.

The Elephant class also has an other property called HasTrunk which is of type `bool`.

So:

```
public class Elephant
{
      public Elephant ClonedFrom { get; set; }
      public  bool     HasTrunk { get; set; }
}
```

and we have

```
   List<Elephant> herd
```

I'd like to have a LINQ query that would return any Elephants that have a false HasTrunk property but also have a ClonedFrom property equal to another Elephant in the same list whose HasTrunk property is set to true.

So for example Elephant A is cloned to create the new elephants B and C

B and C both exist in the herd List. B has HasTrunk set to false whereas C has hasTrunk set to true.

I'd like a query that returns B.

Comment: *I'd like to have a LINQ query...* So write one and come here if you get stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
var results = herd.Where(e => !e.HasTrunk 
                            && e.ClonedFrom != null
                            && e.ClonedFrom.HasTrunk
                            && herd.Contains(e.ClonedFrom));
```

Comment: I'm not sure that that answers my question. I've edited my original post to try and make it clearer what it is that I'm looking for exactly.

Comment: your query looks like it's searching to make sure the original object is in the list (A in my example above). That's not actually important though.

Comment: @Sperick Because your original statement sounds like there is requirement to make sure it's in the list : "...also have a `ClonedFrom` property equal to **another Elephant in the same list**". Anyway, simply scratch the last check from this answer if you don't need it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that how do you check the equality of the Clonedfrom parents? You can selfjoin herd on the Clonedfrom properties, But then you have to check their grandparents too. How far should we go?
You can also use the getHashCode of the parents to check if they are with same reference but I'm not sure if it works in your case:

```
Var results = from h1 in herd
join h2 in herd
on h1.ClonedFrom.getHashCode()
equals
h2.ClonedFrom.getHashCode()
where !h1.hasTrunk && h2.hasTrunk
select h1;
```